# Modification for an SM57?

Tags: sm57, microphone, modification

I was told by a renowned voice over talent that you can modify an SM57 to sound a lot better. It sounded like an electronics mod requiring soldering.

Anyone else heard of this or know where I can find this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the mod is taking out the transformer.  Older 57s don't have a transformer in them, newer ones do.  Basically the mod has you unscrew the bottom of the 57, cut the two wires, boil the bottom half in water to get the epoxy out, take out the transformer, then solder the output of the top half directly to the XLR connector.  The mod ends up giving you a bit more low end / warmth to it.

Sounds a lot easier than it is.  Boiling the bottom half and trying to get out the epoxy - not fun.

You're better off buying an Audix i5.  Sounds like the mod.

The mod was originally posted in Tape Op mag.

EDIT:

I can't find the original article, but here's a guy that wrote out step by step how he did it, and the results. It's exactly the same procedure, so if you're interested in doing it, just follow these steps:

http://www.churchmedia.net/forums/general-audio/17017-shure-sm57-modification-experiment-described.html

Comment: Why do you need to physically remove the transformer if you have access to the wires?  o_O

Comment: @endolith - you actually have access to the wires before you remove the transformer.  You need to physically remove the transformer because it blocks the connection to the XLR connector after you've snipped the wires

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this thread on gearslutz](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/131704-sm57-transformer-mod.html)

Lots of bull$H!7 posts, but a few useful ones, and links.
I never used or heard a modded one myself.